# Restricting ActionController/ActiveResource's map.resources routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a resource exposed with two actions **ONLY** ('name' and 'number') and I would like to have a RESTful interface like:

```
resource/name/1

resource/number/ABC
```

but with the default

```
map.resources :controller_name
```

this doesn't work. How can I add these 2 custom actions? (total n00b here)

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: I managed to get it working backwards :D With: 
<code>
map.resources :pilot_nb_of_running_calls, :member => { :number => :get, :name => :get } 
</code>
I am able to get the opposite of what I want, i.e., 
<code>
/resource/XXX/name 
</code>
works. But I would really like to have 
<code>
/resource/name/XXX
</code>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with a resource. You need to map a custom (named) route.

```
map.connect 'resource/:id/name', :controller => 'resources', :action => 'name'
map.connect 'resource/:id/number', :controller => 'resources', :action => 'number'

# the same but with named routes

map.name_resource 'resource/:id/name', :controller => 'resources', :action => 'name'
map.number_resource 'resource/:id/number', :controller => 'resources', :action => 'number'
```

Comment: second this, you could be even smarter and work out the type of route that you want using a regular expression based on whether the param contained digits only or letters only. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.htm